# Joomla Membership platforms and OPENLDAP

Tags: joomla, paypal, registration, openldap

I have several Joomla sites all tied to the same OPENLDAP security engine.
I am required to stand up a paypal-subscription platform, however most Joomla subscription components force mysql as the backend to manage the users.  Since I have multiple sites all at once, I need to create/manage the accounts on OPENLDAP.

Does anyone know of any registration engines that will use OPENLDAP vice Mysql?  I am also open to any non-joomla registration engines as well.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL doesn't manage users/regsitration, it's just a database. In joomla you manage authentication via authentication plugins and then also user plugins for if you are not using the core user table> Look at the joomla user and authentication plugins and also the ldap plugin that is in the core to help get you started.